# MATLAB going from Cart to Pol back to Cart coords for cylindrical plot

Tags: matlab, plot, coordinate-transformation, polar-coordinates, cylindrical

**1. What I WANT to do:**
**(i)** Use input n to generate an n*n cartesian grid

```
[x y] = meshgrid(linspace(-1,1,n));
```

**(ii)** Generate polar coordinates

```
[theta r] = cart2pol(x,y);
```

**(iii)** Evaluate a function in cylindrical coordinates

```
z = f(theta,r);
```

**(iv)** Plot the result using (say) pcolor (or surf, or anything)

```
pcolor(x,y,abs(z).^2) %The function is complex, a Laguerre-Gauss to be exact.
```

**2. What I CAN do... The only way I can get the plots to work is by starting with my polar parameters and working back to cartesian from there:

(i)** Define parameters

```
r=linspace(0,1,n); theta=linspace(0,2*pi,n);
```

**(ii)** Create both grids and evaluate f

```
[theta r]=meshgrid(theta,r);  
[x y]=pol2cart(theta,r);  
z=f(theta,r);
```

**(iii)** Plot

```
pcolor(x,y,abs(z).^2)
```

The PROBLEM is that now my grid is circular, and I would like to evaluate the function everywhere ON A RECTANGULAR grid (because my analysis depends on having square pixel arrays). The reiterate, using method 2 above, I get a circular plot circumscribed in a square; imagine a black circle with white along the edges... but I WANT to evaluate the function in this "white" region. HOWEVER, using method 1 does NOT work -- the function is all messed up when I plot (Just google Laguerre-Gauss modes to see what the plots should look like).

I want to be able to start with a rect grid and assign every point a polar coordinate, instead of start with polar coordinates and assign them all cartesian points.

I've been messing with this on an off for a long time, and I can't figure out how to get around this seemingly simple issue.

**Edit 1**
It seems that the problem lies in how the coordinate matrices are generated. Below I've posted screen-shots of a simple 3by3 example illustrating how approach 1 and approach 2 generate different numbers.

How to make these numbers compatible?

I have no reputation points so I cannot upload the images directly... links below show the 3by3 example... see comments for links to actual images of the Laguerre-Gauss plots I'm trying to make...

[apply cart2pol](http://i43.tinypic.com/r885zo.png)
[apply pol2cart](http://i42.tinypic.com/dzdxg3.png)

**Edit 2**

Currently, the result of approach (**1.**) gives wrong results, as shown here:

[desired approach, wrong result](http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=a1l2e9&s=5)

The second approach gives the right images, unfortunately it's only a circle and not the entire square. It is shown here:

[implemented approach, limited result](http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2w4les5&s=5)

3D plots of both approaches are shown [here](http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=54zvpe&s=5) - only the colorful part of the top figure is correct.

**Edit 3**

Here is a [screenshot of the function `f`](http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=1ykd8k&s=5) which is being used above. Note, that it asks for more input parameters than just `r,theta`. Typical values are:

```
w0 = 0.5;
p = 0;
l = 5;
```

The function `C` gives a normalization and `L` are Laguerre polynomials. Both of these functions have been thoroughly tested and yield the expected results.

**Edit 4**
Here is enough code to run my example `z=U(0,5,r,phi,w0)+U(0,-5,r,phi,w0);` explicitly. The plot itself is given by `pcolor(x,y,abs(z).^2)`.

Note that the `Lpl()` function is inserted as a comment. This will have to be saved as its own m-file for the U function to run properly.

```
%% Laguerre-Gauss Modes U = U(p,l,r,phi,w0)
%  Source: OAM theory paper section 2.A eqn 1.
%  Assuming POLAR coordinates and evaluating AT beam waist.
% -- That is, z=0 for w(z)=w0(sqrt(1+z/zR)) 
% ---- ie, w(0) = w0
% Assuming z=0 also renders the Gouy phase arctan(z/zR) irrelevant.
% Note: Rayleigh Range zR is not explicitly defined because z=0 --> it is irrelevant too.
% Since zR is the only wavelength dependent term, wavelength also doesn't
% matter.

function out = U(p,l,r,phi,w0)
%Function handles for clarity
e = @(x) exp(x);
C = @(p,l) sqrt((2*factorial(p))/(pi*factorial(p+abs(l))));
L = @(p,l,z) Lpl(p,l,z);

%% Lpl() FUNCTION
% function out = Lpl(p,l,z)
% 
% l=abs(l);
% LL=0;
% for mm=1:p+1
%     m=mm-1;
%     L=LL;
%     LL= L+((-1)^m)*(factorial(p+l)/(factorial(p-m)*factorial(l+m)*factorial(m)))*(z.^m); 
% end
% out = LL;

%% 

out = (C(p,l)/w0)*...
    (((sqrt(2).*r)/w0)^abs(l))*...
    (e((-r.^2)/w0^2))*...
    (L(p,l,((2.*r.^2)/w0^2)))*...
    (e((-1)*1i*l.*phi)); ``
```

Comment: It makes sense that the numbers won't be exactly the same, but a circle of radius 1 should easily map into a cartesian grid that spans (-1,1) in each direction. In my eyes I'm evaluating the function over the same domain (essentially) in each case. Clearly this isn't true... I don't see what I'm missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**
The answer was rewritten based on the code provided in **Edit 4** of the question.

I think the trouble stems from the function `U`. You don't apply [element wise operations](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arithmeticoperators.html) to all parts of the equation. If you change it to:

```
out = (C(p,l)./w0).* ...              % here it's a .* instead of *
    (((sqrt(2).*r)./w0).^abs(l)).* ... % here it's a .* instead of *
    (e((-r.^2)./w0.^2)).* ...          % here it's a .* instead of *
    (L(p,l,((2.*r.^2)./w0.^2))).* ...  % here it's a .* instead of *
    (e((-1)*1i*l.*phi));
```

You get the following two results, shown below.

This figure used an input of cartesian coordinates:

[image]

And this figure used the polar coordinates:

[image]

The "coarser" resolution in the second figure is due to the less suitable resolution of the grid. But in essence you resolve the same features.

Comment: That's it!!! I have tested your solution on around 30 combinations and all give expected results. This was in fact an **elementary error on element-wise multiplication**.

Comment: THHHANNKKK YOUUUUUU!!! My Summer research can finally get going (as these functions are the basis--literally-- for everything I'm doing) :)

Comment: I want to make sure I do everything necessary to get you max props for this. Let me know if I'm forgetting anything (new to the stack).